# Core Data & GCD: Passing the correct managed object context to custom NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I get runtime errors which seem to result from my incorrect implementation of `GCD` in combination with my custom NSManagedObjects.

Nested in a `GCD` call, I am using custom NSManagedObjects which (seem to) have their own managed object contexts (= `self.managedObjectContext`).

I am creating the managed object context in the app delegate by using the managed object context provided by `UIManagedDocument`: `self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext`.

I don't understand how to pass the correct managed object context down to my custom NSManagedObjects. How would I need to change my code to use the correct managed object context?

This is my main method (inside a view controller):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
// ...
NSDecimalNumber *value = [reportedPeriod 
   valueForCoa:figure.code 
   convertedTo:self.currencySymbol];
// ...});
}
```

In this main method I do not have any reference to a managed object context, I do just call `valueForCoa:convertedTo:` (which is coded as follows):

```
- (NSDecimalNumber*)valueForCoa:(NSString*)coaStr
convertedTo:(NSString*)targetCurrencyStr {
// ...
CoaMap *coa = [CoaMap coaItemForString:coaStr
   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
// ...
}
```

`valueForCoa` is a method in my custom subclassed NSManagedObject `ReportedPeriod` and uses its (default) managed object context `self.managedObjectContext`.

The app then usually crashes in the custom subclassed NSManagedObject `CoaMap` in the following method when it executes the fetch request:

```
+ (CoaMap*)coaItemForString:(NSString*)coaStr 
inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context {

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest 
fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
NSPredicate *predicate = 
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"coa == %@",coaStr];
   request.predicate = predicate;
// ** The runtime error occurs in the following line **
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
// ...
}
```

The error message is: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x9a8a4a0> was mutated while being enumerated.`

Could you please help me with this issue and give me some suggestions on how to improve my code to pass the correct managed object contexts (or on how to make sure that the correct context is used in all methods)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `GCD` does not stand for `Greatest Common Divisor` and I have removed that tag. Also, which line are you getting this error on (I'm not seeing any enumeration code)?

Comment: @Robotic Cat, I have updated my question (including the `GrandCentralDispatch` tag). The error occurs in the line where `executeFetchRequest` happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error generally relates to using a managed object incorrectly context across different threads or queues. You created the MOC on the main queue, but you're using it on a background queue without considering that fact. It's not *wrong* to use the MOC on a background queue, but you need to be aware of that and take preparations.

You didn't say how you're creating the MOC. I suggest that you *should* be doing this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
    initWithConcurrencyType: NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

With main queue concurrency you can just use it normally on the main thread. When you're in your dispatch queue though, do this:

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest 
        fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    NSPredicate *predicate = 
       [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"coa == %@",coaStr];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    // ...
}];
```

This will ensure that the MOC's work occurs on the main thread even though you're on a background queue. (Technically what it actually means is that the MOC's work in the background will be correctly synchronized with work it does on the main queue, but the result is the same: this is the safe way to do this).

A similar approach would be to use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` instead. If you do that, you'd use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` everywhere for the MOC, not just on background threads.

Comment: Tom Harrington, I have updated my question to include the managed object I am using: I am creating the managed object context in the app delegate by using the managed object context provided by `UIManagedDocument`(=`self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext`). In this case, would I rather follow your approach (concurrency type: `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`) or would I rather use: `context.parentContext = self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext;    [context performBlock:^{..}]`?

Comment: @AlexR, since you're using `UIManagedDocument`, you already have main queue concurrency. Use `performBlockAndWait` in the background, but you can leave the `UIManagedDocument` creation unchanged.

Comment: Generally when using `performBlock` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` do you use it in combination with GCD (e.g. `dispatch_async(queue, ^{
});`or just `[context performBlock...]` alone?

Comment: Those are completely independent of each other. Use `dispatch_async` if you want to do some work on a different queue. Use `performBlock` if you want to use the same MOC on more than one queue.

Comment: For a long-running calculation (or download) which requires about 3 seconds and does a lot of core data fetching and writing, would you recommend using `performBlock` and `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` (and no GCD) or a combination of both? I assume that `performBlock` and `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` is always executed on a background thread and never blocks the UI (?)

Comment: For that situation I'd use GCD to get onto a background thread and either (a) use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for my MOC (you're right, it won't block the UI) or (b) create a second MOC on the background queue, then merge changes into the main MOC when finished.

Comment: When using `performBlock` and `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` on the main method, how do I get `[reportedPeriod valueForCoa:figure.code convertedTo:self.currencySymbol]` to use the same (background) thread context? This method has no parameter to specify a managed object context. By the way, I have added `self.managedObjectContext performBlock` to the destination method to ensure that it runs on the correct block (but still do get crashes).

Comment: This is getting pretty long for comments. Apple provides extensive documentation and sample code-- I suggest you take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First,

> "how to pass the correct managed object context down to my custom NSManagedObjects."

We create `NSManagedObject` with `NSManagedObjectContext`. not the other way around. So, when you have a `NSManagedObject`, you can access the `NSManagedObjectContext` by asking its property: `– managedObjectContext` as listed in [**Apple Document**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html)

Second,

When working with CoreData, multi-threading could be a little tricky. especially for the beginner. The are all kind of details that you need to take care of.

I highly recommend you checkout the `Parent-Child NSManagedContext`. then, using [**MagicRecord**](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).

By using [**MagicRecord**](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), you can simply Grand Central Dispatch with a Block like this:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){

    // here use the `localContext` as your NSManagedContext and do things in the background.
    // it will take care of all the rest.

}];
```

If you need to pass `NSManagedObject` into this block, remember to only pass the `NSManagedObjectID` instead of the proprety.

this is a example.

```
NSManagedObjectID *coaMapID = CoaMap.objectID;

[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    coaMap *aCoaMap = (coaMap *)[localContext existingObjectWithID:coaMapID error:&error];
    // then use aCoaMap normally.
}];
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Kyle, what is the advantage of using MagicalRecord's `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` vs `[context performBlock...]` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` introduced in iOS 5?

Comment: the awesome advantage is that you don't need the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, the `BackgroundThread`, the `performBlock` and the `save` and so much more. It does it all. let you focus what you really need to do.